# How to make TextView's text size based on device screen size in android

Tags: android

i have one app  which can be runs on different screen size from 3.7 Inches to 6.0 inches(no plan for tablet now).

now i have TextView which have **17dp for title** and **14dp description**. but when i run the app in small device (3.7-4.7 inches screen size device) the textview's text is big.

But the same textview in higher 5.5 or 5.7 this can be small .

**so how can i make TextView  looks same for all device.**

Comment: Are you using "sp" or "dp" for text size ? I

Comment: right now i use dp. text size in sp works.(right now i don't know about sp)

Comment: take a look here it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dip-dp-and-sp

Comment: use "sp" to set textSize for TextView. It is Scale-independent Pixels and can automate scale to appropriate to different screen size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue and I used [this](https://github.com/intuit/ssp) library and it did the thing for me.

The thing is you just have to replace sp with ssp in your xml after adding this library in your gradle and you'll be good to go.

Comment: let me try . i will inform you once i satisfy with my requirement.

Comment: thanks sir . your answer is works . i marked your answer as accepted answer. once again thank you sir.

Answer (score 2):

As screen size is between 3.7 and 6.0 you should only create 1 additional dimens files like sw480 and use dp-s for TextView dimensions and sp for text size. In default dimens file you should write sizes for devices with smallest screen sizes e.g. for 3.7‘, and comparably bigger dimens in sw480 file e.g for 5.5‘ screens.  Based on particular cases additional dimens files can be created like sw360. If screen is less than 360 dp width，it will use the values from default dimens file, if 360dp <= screen size < 480dp then sw360 will be used. The same simple logic works for each created sw dimens file.

Answer (score 1):

Create multiple dimens.xml for your project, it will give size according to the display size

You Have to create multiple values folder and have to create dimens.xml inside them.
A reference for those folders are:

```
values-sw720dp          10.1” tablet 1280x800 mdpi

values-sw600dp          7.0”  tablet 1024x600 mdpi

values-sw480dp          5.4”  480x854 mdpi 
values-sw480dp          5.1”  480x800 mdpi 

values-xxhdpi           5.5"  1080x1920 xxhdpi
values-xxxhdpi           5.5" 1440x2560 xxxhdpi

values-xhdpi            4.7”   1280x720 xhdpi 
values-xhdpi            4.65”  720x1280 xhdpi 

values-hdpi             4.0” 480x800 hdpi
values-hdpi             3.7” 480x854 hdpi

values-mdpi             3.2” 320x480 mdpi

values-ldpi             3.4” 240x432 ldpi
values-ldpi             3.3” 240x400 ldpi
values-ldpi             2.7” 240x320 ldpi
```

Comment: thank you for answer but i like above answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48107349/8203967

Comment: Cool, No Problem. Welcome

Answer (score 1):

In android you are dealing with dp/sp values. Don't think of physical size. 
There's this nifty plugin that lets you convert your sp/dp values to different buckets. You can add
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9349-dimenify

Comment: thank you for answer but i like above answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48107349/8203967